# How to prompt the user to choose default navigation application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have an app which let the user click on the address to start the navigation from his current position. For now it open [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze&referrer=utm_source%3Dgmm%26utm_campaign%3Dgmm_android). But now I want to let user to choose between maps, waze and other navigation app installed and make one default.

I tried using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.US, "geo:%.8f,%.8f", latitude, longitude)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));
```

It let me choose but it not start the navigation, just a classique point on a map. What I want is to open the navigation of any app.
for map it's :

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

But it does not let the user which application to use.

So is there a way to do that automatically ? if not what can be the alternative to let the user choose ?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");` you are forcing to use Google Maps. From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29):

> **public Intent setPackage (String packageName)**
>
> (Usually optional) Set an explicit application package name that limits the components this Intent will resolve to. If left to the default value of null, all components in all applications will considered. If non-null, the Intent can only match the components in the given application package.

Just remove it:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that Waze responds to `http://maps.google.com` Intents, so you can achieve your desired functionality this way (does not work for iCoyote):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: I already tried without, It does the same, directly open google map .

Comment: What navigation apps do you have installed? Try removing the "Launch by default" options for Google Maps. Go to Settings->Apps->Maps->Clear Defaults

Comment: I have, maps, Waze, iCoyote, 3 main app used here in France. Clear Defaults change nothing. Maybe the other app just doesn't catch this intent "google.navigation" ? (which is stupid in 2016)

Comment: I have tried Nokia Here and OsmAnd and both work well, but I can confirm that neither Waze nor iCoyote respond to `google.navigation` Intent

Comment: I just tried with "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" and it seems to works, not perfectly because depending of the app it does not start directly the navigation... Is there a way to combine multiple URI to cacth maximum app as possible ?

Comment: Not directly, but you can detect what packages are installed and show a dialog (or even better, a bottom toolbar) to let the user choose how to navigate (and in this case, use `intent.setPackage` to force a given app and pass the correct url to the selected application).